# Compare two lists to determine if both lists contain same items using lambda predicates

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, lambda, predicate

I am trying to return a boolean value if my object list contains all the types in a list of types in either vb.net or C#. I am struggling in writing a lambda expression to accomplish this. Can this be done using lambda predicates? I know it can be done easily with a for each loop.

vb.net

```
Public Class Widget
    Public wobbly As String
    Public sprocket As String
    Public bearing As String
End Class

Public Sub test()
    Dim wList As New List(Of Widget)
    wList.Add(New Widget() With {.bearing = "xType", .sprocket = "spring", .wobbly = "99"})
    wList.Add(New Widget() With {.bearing = "yType", .sprocket = "sprung", .wobbly = "45"})
    wList.Add(New Widget() With {.bearing = "zType", .sprocket = "straight", .wobbly = "17"})

    Dim typeList As New List(Of String) From {"xType", "yType", "zType"}

    Dim containsAllTypes As Boolean = wList.TrueForAll(Function(a) a.bearing.Equals(typeList.Where(Function(b) b = a.bearing)))
    Debug.WriteLine(containsAllTypes.ToString)
End Sub
```

C#

```
public class Widget
{
    public string wobbly;
    public string sprocket;
    public string bearing;
}

public void test()
{
    List<Widget> wList = new List<Widget>();
    wList.Add(new Widget {
        bearing = "xType",
        sprocket = "spring",
        wobbly = "99"
    });
    wList.Add(new Widget {
        bearing = "yType",
        sprocket = "sprung",
        wobbly = "45"
    });
    wList.Add(new Widget {
        bearing = "zType",
        sprocket = "straight",
        wobbly = "17"
    });

    List<string> typeList = new List<string> {
        "xType",
        "yType",
        "zType"
    };

    bool containsAllTypes = wList.TrueForAll(a => a.bearing.Equals(typeList.Where(b => b == a.bearing)));
    Debug.WriteLine(containsAllTypes.ToString());
}
```

EDIT, thanks for all the quick answers, I see there are a few ways to do this, and now have a better understanding of what is happening in the expression.

Comment: What if `wList` contains two items with `xType`? And what problems with your current code? Can you show (in c# pseudo code) what you trying to achive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var containsAll = typeList.All(type => 
    wList.Any(widget => widget.bearing.Equals(type)));
```

Translated, it is true for all types in `typeList` that any (at least one) widget in the list has that type.

Comment: I am trying to validate that all types exist in the list, not just one.

Comment: Yes, that was my understanding. For all types in `typeList` there must be at least one matching widget in `wList`.

Comment: Maybe I am not stating it as clearly as I could, but I am wanting to make sure that all items in `typeList` correspond to an item in `wList` so that I compare each item in `wList` to make sure it is also in `typeList`

Comment: In this case I think the number of answers suggests a lack of clarity. "if my object list contains all the types in a list of types." If `wList` contains all of the types in `typeList`? That was my understanding.

Comment: Okay, after going over your logic I see what it is doing now, I thought at first it was just checking if `any` one of the types existed, but I see how it is using the `all` and then doing the conditional

Comment: This answer and Matt.G answer is right, all of other answers are checking in wrong road

Answer (score 3):

Try `var containsAllTypes = typeList.All(x => wList.Select(x => x.bearing).Contains(x))`

Comment: This solution works as well, I think the logic is basically the same using `Contains` or as in Scott Hannen's answer using `Any` as long as it it prefixed with the `All` predicate so checks each one.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is the following:

```
bool containsAllTypes1 = wList.TrueForAll(a => null != typeList.Find(b => b == a.bearing));
```

You can also use System.Linq as follows:

```
bool containsAllTypes2 = wList.All(a => typeList.Any(b => b == a.bearing));
```

Answer (score 1):

The shorter is

```
containsAllTypes = wList.Where(x => typeList.Contains(x.bearing)).Count() == typeList.Count;
```

or

```
containsAllTypes =  wList.Select(x => x.bearing).Except(typeList).Count() == 0;
```

or

```
containsAllTypes =  wList.Select(x => x.bearing).Intersect(typeList).Count() == typeList.Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim containsAllTypes As Boolean = wList.All(Function(a) typeList.Any(Function(b) b = a.bearing))
```

For each value in wList, it checks to see if any values in typeList match the wList bearing value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Intersect` to check if both list has same values. Try this code

```
var hasAll = wList
 .Select(w => w.bearing)
 .Distinct()
 .Intersect(typeList)
 .Count() == typeList.Count;
```

If you need to have `hasAll == true` only if all types in `wList` occured once,  remove call to `Distinct`